# What is the English for "地宮"?

Tags: translation, meaning

I know that "underground palace" can be a translation of "地宮", but I'm not too sure on the "correct" translation.

Seeing some pictures on [baike](http://www.baike.com/wiki/%E5%9C%B0%E5%AE%AB), "underground palace" doesn't really seem to fit what the pictures depict.

From what I see, I think that something like "underground maze" would suit it better, stemming from "迷宮". However, with the English translation of "underground palace", should the "palace" then not be taken literally as a "palace"? I'm a bit confused since from the pictures, "地宮" seems to be more like an "underground tomb" than a "palace".

Comment: 迷宮  "underground maze" is labyrinth

Comment: It depends on the contexts.

Answer (score 1):

Without the context its kind of hard to know which definition you're looking for, but **Oxford** gives us two definitions with explanations:

> NOUN
>
> 1 地下陵墓 tomb chamber

Underground tomb/mausoleum

> 2 地下藏经室 underground shrine housing Buddhist relics

Buddhist sutras collection room

Answer (score 1):

If we go along the definition found in the Baike link you provided:

```
...为安放死者棺椁的地方。...
```

then we could probably use "**burial chamber**" as used in similar structures inside a pyramid.

Sketch showing pyramid interior structure: http://www.ancient-egypt.org/_v3d/topography/giza/khefren/map3d.gif

That said, it seems to me that the literal translation of "underground palace" is a valid and quite poetic rendering in English and might be better in certain contexts.

Answer (score -1):

how about tomb palace? it is indeed a tomb

Answer (score -1):

If you talk about games there are many games named that as "Dungeon".

Answer (score -1):

I think that crypt is what you want.